# Hibernate Migration | Hibernate 6.2.5 | Error while executing JPQL Query in Cloud

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpql

```
For the below JPQL Query:


"Select o from CustomJDO o where customDt \>= 
SYSDATE-?1 and jlow is NOT null and customerCode not in (?2) and 
customerOwner='SM' and customerType=6 and UPPER(additionalFields) like 
'%"JLOCUSTOMERACTIONS"\>CONN%'".

I'm trying to migrate this query to Hibernate 6.2.5 and ran a local testing in my eclipse and it worked. I updated the query as below:
```

> Select o from CustomJDO o where customDt >= CURRENT_DATE - CAST(?1
> AS int) and jlowis NOT null and customerCode not in (?2) and
> customerOwner='SM' and customerType=6 and
> UPPER(CAST(o.additionalFieldsAS string)) like
> '%"JLOCUSTOMERACTIONS">TRUE%'
>
> ```
> ?1 : Integer no_of_days
> ?2 : List\<BigDecimal\> notOpenOrderStates.
> ```

Now, when I'm trying to deploy the application in cloud, it throws the below exception:

```
`Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '"'
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2750)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2671)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625)
at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4141)
at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.doLogf(Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.java:81)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logf(Logger.java:2445)
at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.debugf(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:344)
at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:75)
at      org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:747)
at     org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
at   org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
at  org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:126)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy161.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94)
```

`I ran the updated query in local environment using eclipse. I was using open jdk version 17.0.7 and it worked correctly. But when I ran the application in GCP, it is throwing an exception.\`